# How to enforce typing of route params?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript-framework

I have set up the following paths:

```
this.resource('areaManagement',    { path: '/management/areas' }, function() {
  this.route('assign',    { path: '/assign' });
  this.route('new',       { path: '/new' });
  this.route('subdivide', { path: '/:id' });
});
```

If you wanted to create a new area, you would go to `/management/areas/new`, but in testing, I accidentally went to `/management/areas/create` and noticed no error was thrown. Then I realized, this path is matching the `subdivide` dynamic segment.

If this is how dynamic segments work, then technically, `/management/areas/anythingyouwant` will be a valid/recognized path. I could always implement a `model()` hook and redirect/error if `:id` isn't an integer, but **is there a way to make the router enforce this?**

Answer (score 0):

I think an "easy" workaround would be to add a new nesting level by adding a

```
path: '/id'
```

to have a URL like

```
/management/areas/id/1
```

Not necessarily idealbut would help you here.